# ES6 Modules : Importing a module in an Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have an ES6 module where I am exporting a library. I want to be able to use this module in an Angular component. I cannot have the library files locally within my Angular app, neither can I publish the library as an NPM package.

Can I host the module in a dev server, and use the server URL to import the module in my Angular component?

I tried things like

**component.ts**

```
import * as lib from "...url";
```

or adding this in **index.html**

```
<script src = "..url"/>
```

Neither of them have worked. What can I try next?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://verdaccio.org/ maybe this will be useful for you

Comment: @JoanSanchez, so I’m aiming for something like a dynamic import, so I can use import statement based on a condition. Is there a way I can do it with the import statement using a url?

Comment: "*I cannot have the library files locally within my Angular app, neither can I publish the library as an NPM package.*" - why? What are your actual constraints?